# Why $u_{k_m}\rightharpoonup u\quad \text{in}\quad H_0^1(U)$ implies $(Du_{k_m},Dg)\to(Du,Dg)\;\;\forall g\in H^1_0(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u_k\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ bounded, then exists a subsequence $\{u_{k_m}\}\subset\{u_k\}$ such that
$$u_{k_m}\rightharpoonup u\quad \text{in}\quad H_0^1(U)$$
Then (why ?)$$\int_{\Omega}Du_{k_m}\cdot Dg\;dx\to\int_{\Omega}Du\cdot Dg\;dx,\;\;\;\forall g\in H^1_0(\Omega)\;\;\;{(1)}$$
Also, (why ?)
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^md_iw_i,\;\;d_i\in\mathbb{R}\;\;(2)$$
is dense in $H^1_0(\Omega),$ where $\{w_i\}$ be the family of all eigenfunctions of $-\Delta$ with zero Dirichlet boundary conditions and it's an orthogonal basis on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and orthonormal on $L_{2}(\Omega).$ Why $(1)$ and $(2)$ it is true?

Comment: Also for (1), $(u,v):=\int Du\cdot Dv \, dx$ is an equivalent inner product on $H^1_0$, due to the Poincare inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The embedding $\iota: H_{0}^{1}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{2}(\Omega)$ is continuous (actually, it is even compact by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem). Continuous linear operators map weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent sequences, therefore $u_{k_m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Now, for any $g \in H_0^1 (\Omega)$, we have

$$(\nabla u_{k_m},\nabla g)_{L^{2}(\Omega)} = (u_{k_m},g)_{H_0^{1}(\Omega)} - (u_{k_m},g)_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$$ Taking the limit $k\to \infty$, we obtain$$ (u,g)_{H_0^{1}(\Omega)} - (u_,g)_{L^{2}(\Omega)} = (\nabla u,\nabla g)_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

which proves (1).

For the second question, $$\begin{align} T: \text{dom}(T) \subseteq & L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)\\ &u \mapsto -\Delta u\end{align}$$ is an unbounded, but densely defined closed operator on $L^{2}(\Omega)$, where $\text{dom}(T) =\{u \in C_{c}^{\infty}({\Omega}) : u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0\}$. It can be shown, (you will find the proof in any book on partial differential equations, see e.g. Evans) that $T^{-1}$ is compact and self-adjoint, which implies that it can be expanded in terms of countably many orthonormal eigenfunctions (we may ignore the eigenvalue $0$ in the expansion). These eigenfunctions are also orthonormal eigenfunctions of $T$. Let's denote the complete system of eigenfunctions of orthonormal eigenfunctions of $T$ by $\{w_i\}$. Note that $T$ is a positive operator, hence all eigenvalues are positive.

Now let $w_1, w_2 $ be two eigenfunctions of $T$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Then
$$(w_1,w_2)_{H_0^1} = (\nabla w_1, \nabla w_2)_{L^2} + (w_1,w_2)_{L^2} = (\nabla w_1, \nabla w_2)_{L^2} = (-\Delta w_1,w_2)_{L^2}\\ = \lambda_1 (w_1,w_2)_{L^2} = 0.$$ 
which shows that the system $\{w_i\}$ is orthogonal in $H_0^1$. For the completeness, let $v \in H_0^1$ such that $(v,w_i)_{H_0^1} = 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then,

$$(v,w_i)_{H_0^1} = (\nabla v, \nabla w_i)_{L^2} + (v,w_i)_{L^2} = (v,-\Delta w_i)_{L^2} + (v,w_i)_{L^2} \\= (1 +\lambda_i) (v,w_i)_{L^2} = 0. $$
Because $\lambda_i \geq 0$, this implies $(v,w_i)_{L^2} = 0$ for all $i \in\mathbb{N}$. As $v \in L^2$ and $w_i$ is a complete orthonormal system in $L^2$, this in turn implies $v = 0$.